# Getting Asynchronous Sessions cleanup phase starting NOW using Phantomjs

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

I am using **PhantomJs 1.9.8** , **Python 2.7.6**

I got   [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345767/repeating-asynchronous-sessions-cleanup-phase-starting-now) but do not know how to change **(with a wee bit of JavaScript)**  and  I do also not have enough reputation to comment.

My program hang on for long time. When I googled I found this problem on  [github link](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11526), and they said because of **Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW** PhantomJs is unstable and some guys also moved Phantomjs to Firefox or chrome.

In my case I have tried Firefox or chrome, usually I get exception browser is crashed so I moved to PhantomJs.Now I am totally confused what to do.

**Ghostdriver.log file**

```
Asynchronous Sessions cleanup phase starting NOW
Asynchronous Sessions cleanup phase starting NOW
Asynchronous Sessions cleanup phase starting NOW
Asynchronous Sessions cleanup phase starting NOW.....
```

Is there anyone has solved this Problem or anything else which is stable?

Comment: I get the same on Ubuntu 15 w/ Python 2.7.9. It is transient and you can find traces of this issue all the way back to PhantonJS 1.9.1. It also seems that timeouts do not really have an impact as otherwise if you had an issue accessing a webpage it would disconnect after timeout. 98% of the time my code works w/o an issue. On one or two occasions I managed to resolve the issue by either bouncing the server and/or changing the ulimit for file handlers. Try that if you can.

Comment: You might also have an issue with close/quit or general cleanup. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110624/how-to-properly-stop-phantomjs-execution

Comment: @goggelj I used this method but the problem did not fix!