# PhantomJS: SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation, phantomjs

I'm trying to write some automated tests that can be run on multiple clients. The problem is on different pages on different clients I get this message in the log repeating, it sometimes takes a few minutes to stop or in some cases I just kill the test and have to start again:

```
[INFO  - 2015-12-04T09:36:56.763Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
[INFO  - 2015-12-04T09:37:11.708Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
[INFO  - 2015-12-04T09:37:11.709Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Deleted Session 'e5f06a10-9a69-11e5-a73d-1d612c039e5a', because windowless
[INFO  - 2015-12-04T09:40:01.395Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
[INFO  - 2015-12-04T09:40:17.132Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
[INFO  - 2015-12-04T09:41:56.773Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
```

I've seen many people have the same issue but can't find a solution to it. The nearest I could find was this [Repeating "Asynchronous Sessions cleanup phase starting NOW"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345767/repeating-asynchronous-sessions-cleanup-phase-starting-now)

The answer says its to do with calling external feeds and some javascript can be used to remove these calls but it doesn't give an example of how to do this.

If this is the problem can somebody tell me how I can remove the calls using javascript or if there is another way I can stop this problem from happening or even if I can just reduce the number of attempts to try and do the cleanup

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer but I seem to have fixed it by using driver.quit(); instead of driver.close()l between tests. I've ran it a number of times and not had the problem since. The test suite will run multiple times over the weekend so fingers crossed!

Comment: this is a known bug https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11526 for over 2 years I hope you are lucky!

Comment: Had the problem again this morning so I guess that didn't fix it. Sucks its a known bug and no fix or workaround :(

Comment: go and contribute in the issue maybe add a test case if you have an easy one so the devs can fix it