# How to stop this "Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW" in java

Tags: java, phantomjs

i have used `PhantomJS` to take screenshot in java and all is perfect but i got this `Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW`
 in my console

this error is killing me and i cant found any solutions pls help :/

this is the code :

```
public class Screenshot {
private PhantomJSDriver driver;


public  void screen () throws IOException {

    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "D:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");

    this.driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:18383/webpfe/map2.jsf");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1200,800));
    File source = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File ("d:\\test.png"),true);
```

Comment: It seems that is a known bug: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11526

Comment: But no one have found how to fix it :'(

Answer (score 0):

Nearest answer available:

> The Asynchronous Sessions cleanup phase starting NOW ... was caused by
>   some calls to external feeds, these were intermittently slow. This
>   phase must have been waiting for these calls, which were timing out,
>   but PhantomJS sat there waiting for a very, very long time.
>
> Removing these calls when testing (with a wee bit of JavaScript, if
>   host is localhost then use a dummy object) solved the problem.

[Repeating "Asynchronous Sessions cleanup phase starting NOW"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345767/repeating-asynchronous-sessions-cleanup-phase-starting-now)